# SQL: How to filter rows in SQL based on existence of a 2 different column's value against one ID?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following columns:

```
Row Number         |         ID         | Type
1.                           01             A
2.                           01             B
3.                           02             A
4.                           03             B
```

I want to filter the Tableased on the condition that for a given ID, if both type `A` and `B` exists, then it should keep only Type `B` but if it doesn't exists then it shouldn't do anything.

So in this case the resultant table would look like:

```
Row Number         |         ID         | Type
2.                           01             B
3.                           02             A
4.                           03             B
```

How can I achieve this ?

Where table the original table name is `t`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to know if for Type A, Type B exists, which sounds like a use-case for *exists*

```
select *
from t
where not exists (
  select * from t t2 
  where t2.Id = t.Id and t2.Type = 'B' and t.Type = 'A'
);
```

Comment: I see... and I assume `t` is the original table name right? and what is t2? I am getting a little confused there.

Comment: `t` is "a table" from your question - `t2` is an alias used to correlate rows in the subquery with the original table.

Comment: Oh alright got it so you mean that when using `not exists` t2 is expected to be automatically injected. Thank you very much, this was extremely helpful learned something new!